# Goo ball following mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html, mouse-cursor

do you know how the mouse following effect showed on this site was made?
https://pygar.co/en

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code of this page, It not canvas but html div manipulate by java script

1. They have a div with class **pointer__wrapper** that fit the window size
2. Insize the **pointer__wrapper** they have **pointer__wrapper--small** and **pointer__wrapper--big** to handle the small circle and larger circle
3. In **[app.js](https://pygar.com/js/app.e25645e5.js)** file, they have javascript to handle event mouse hover through every element. The small circle and big circle be manipulated (resize, move) depend on the hovered element.